# I don't understand what's going on in my return statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help understanding whats going on in the function, especially the return statements. I know what the return statements do but not how they do it. I know that they format the string but I just don't understand how its being done. It would help if you guys take it step by step.

```
def intF(n, d, l=40):

    s=str(n*10**l / d) 
    if len(s) < l: 
        return '0.{:0>{width}}'.format(s,width=l) 
    if len(s) > l: 
        return s[0:len(s)-l]+'.'+s[len(s)-l:]  

    return '0.'+s
```

Comment: @ daniel i meant what the if statements return

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a line-by-line breakdown:

```
def intF(n, d, l=40):
```

Pretty obvious. `n` is a number, `d` is another number (the divisor) and `l` is the number of digits to print after the decimal point.

```
    s=str(n*10**l / d)
```

This does something a bit unusual. Rather than relying on floating point arithmetic, this multiplies `n` by `10 ** l`, i.e. by a `1` followed by `l` digits. That way the final result won't have any floating point error -- assuming `d` is always an integer. (But of course any remaining digits get truncated. Also, replace `/` with `//` in Python 3 to get the same behavior.)

At this point, `s` will be a string representation of a whole number -- again assuming `d` is an integer -- but it will have the same *digits* as the result of `float(n) / d`. So now we just have to insert the decimal point in the right place.

```
    if len(s) < l: 
        return '0.{:0>{width}}'.format(s,width=l)
```

If the length of `s` is less than `l`, then we need to pad it and prepend a `0.`. That's what this does. The `{:0>{width}}` field says to create a zero-padded field of `width` width, and insert a value into it on the right (`>`) side. Then `s` is passed in via `format`, and we have our result.

```
    if len(s) > l: 
        return s[0:len(s)-l]+'.'+s[len(s)-l:]
```

If the length of `a` is greater than `l`, then we need to insert the decimal point in the correct spot. That's what this does. It removes the trailing `l` digits from `s`, appends a `.`, and then appends the remaining `l` digits.

```
    return '0.'+s
```

The final possibility is that `s` is exactly `l` digits long. In that case, we don't need to do any padding; we can just prepend a `0` and a decimal point.

As a final note: if you pass anything but integers to this function, it will not work as expected. Consider this:

```
>>> intF(10, 10.1, 10)
'990.0990099.01'
```

Or this:

```
>>> intF(10.1, 10, 10)
'101.00000000.0'
```

Comment: this was great thx. im actually new to this so could u tell me what "pad" means. i know that prepend means to add something in front of it so does pad mean to make space?

Comment: Doesn't work if `n` is not an integer, either. Can be easily fixed by using `s=str(int(n)*10**int(l) / int(d))`

Comment: "pad" just means to fill up a field with a particular character. So consider these three strings: `'52'`, `'  52'`, `'0052'`. The first is unpadded. The second is padded with spaces. The third is padded with zeros.

Comment: @senderle ok that makes sense. also i realized i didnt actuually understand this part as well as i thought at first. "The {:0>{width}} field says to create a zero-padded field of width width, and insert a value into it on the right (>) side". would it be possible for u to explain it further? such as what the width and > do. thx.

Comment: @321, I'm assuming you want me to explain string formatting. That's really a separate topic but here's a quick primer: `'{}'.format(5)` -> `'5'`; `'{:02}'.format(5)` -> `'05'`; `'{:04}'.format(5)` -> `'0005'`; `'{:0{width}}'.format(5, width=4)` -> `'0005'`; `'{:0<{width}}'.format(5, width=4)` -> `'5000'`. Read [this](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) slowly and carefully if you want to fully understand string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The line `s=str(n*10**l / d)` converts the ratio `n/d` to an integer by multiplying it by `10**l` to get `l` digits to the right of the decimal point.

After that it tests the number of digits in the result. If it's less than 'l', the ratio was less than 0.1. If it's greater than 'l', it's greater than or equal to 1.0. If it's in between, the ratio was between 0.1 and 1.0.

The expression `'0.{:0>{width}}'.format(s,width=l)` is a fancy way of putting a leading '0.' in front and filling in the necessary number of '0's to get it to `l` decimal points.

The expression `s[0:len(s)-l]+'.'+s[len(s)-l:]` just puts a decimal point in the middle of the string at the proper position.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a string based on the variables you've passed to the function.  It then checks the length of the string, and if it's less than 1, returns with it's format, greater than 1, it's format, and as a fallback default for when it's 1 char in length, another format is returned.

Comment: Actually, that's not a `1` -- it's an `l`.

Comment: I was about to ask how a string representation of a number is ever going to be <1 :D

Comment: could u explain the return statements with more detail plz? i only understand what theyre doing but not how theyre doing it.